# How to implement touch events for iOS with plain javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a plain javascript which is used to drag and move the DIV tags in HTML page
this works fine with the mouse move, mouse up and mouse down events
Now i want to extend this and make it work for touch devices(iPhones)
Can someone help me to do that

```
 if (document.getElementById) {

        (function () {

            var n = 500;
            var dragok = false;
            var y, x, d, dy, dx;

            function move(e) {
                if (!e) e = window.event;
                if (dragok) {
                    d.style.left = dx + e.clientX - x + "px";
                    d.style.top = dy + e.clientY - y + "px";
                    return false;
                }
            }

            function down(e) {
                if (!e) e = window.event;
                var temp = (typeof e.target != "undefined") ? e.target : e.srcElement;
                if (temp.tagName != "HTML" | "BODY" && temp.className != "dragclass") {
                    temp = (typeof temp.parentNode != "undefined") ? temp.parentNode : temp.parentElement;
                }
                if (temp.className == "dragclass") {
                    dragok = true;
                    temp.style.zIndex = n++;
                    d = temp;
                    dx = parseInt(temp.style.left + 0);
                    dy = parseInt(temp.style.top + 0);
                    x = e.clientX;
                    y = e.clientY;
                    document.onmousemove = move;
                    return false;
                }
            }

            function up() {
                dragok = false;
                document.onmousemove = null;
            }

            document.onmousedown = down;
            document.onmouseup = up;

            document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", down, true);
            document.body.addEventListener("touchcancel", up, true);
            document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", move, true);


        })();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have the events: touchstart, touchmove and touchend. They will work the same way

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Touch_events

the best way to implement this would be to test if the browser is capable of touch, through a library like Modernizr, or like:

```
var isTouch = "ontouchstart" in window;

if(isTouch){
   el.addEventListener('touchstart', handlerStart);
   el.addEventListener('touchmove', handlerMove);
   el.addEventListener('touchend', handlerEnd);
} else{
   el.addEventListener('mousedown', handlerStart);
   el.addEventListener('mousemove', handlerMove);
   el.addEventListener('mouseup', handlerEnd);
}
```

Depending on the complexity of what you want to do, the handlers could be the same for both situations, but you will probably have to use different handlers for mouse and touch

Comment: I think this is for canvas, in my case i am not using a canvas and just using a plain javascript to move the div object. Updated the code in the question